# Getting row and column numbers of valid elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix, populated with NaN and values of a variable:

```
NaN 7   NaN
5   NaN 0
NaN NaN 4

matrix = [NaN 7 NaN; 5 NaN 0; NaN NaN 4]
```

I would like to get the row and column numbers of non-NaN cells and put them in a matrix together with the value of the variable. That is, I would like to obtain the following matrix:

```
row col value
1   2   7
2   1   5
2   3   0
3   3   4

want = [1   2   7; 2   1   5; 2   3   0; 3   3   4]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work!

```
[p,q]=find(~isnan(matrix)) % Loops through matrix to find indices

want = zeros(numel(p),3) % three columns you need with same number of rows as p

for i=1:numel(p)
    want[i,:] = [p(i) q(i) matrix(p(i), matrix(i))]
end
```

Should give you the correct result which is:

```
 2     1     5
 1     2     7
 2     3     0
 3     3     4
```

Comment: Dear @ha9u63ar, thank you so much for your solution!! For future readers of the post, z[i,:] should be replaced by z(i,:) and a(p(i), q(i)) should be replaced by matrix(p(i), q(i)) .

Comment: @user3618451    silly me. Thanks for pointing this out! I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without loops:

```
[jj, ii, kk] = find((~isnan(matrix).*(reshape(1:numel(matrix), size(matrix)))).');
result = [ii jj matrix(kk)];
```

The trick is to multiply `~isnan(matrix)` by a matrix of indices so that the third output of [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) gives the [linear index](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) of non-`NaN` entries. The transpose is needed to have the same order as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the ordering of the rows, you can use a simplified version of *Luis Mendo's* answer:

```
[row, col] = find(~isnan(matrix));
result = [row(:), col(:), matrix(~isnan(matrix))];
```

Which will result in:

```
 2     1     5
 1     2     7
 2     3     0
 3     3     4
```